# Format numbers with commas

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am using

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##")
```

when trying to format numbers, but only numbers greater than seven digits get formatted with commas. So, `1000000` gets converted to `1,000,000`, but `1000` does not get converted to `1,000`. Is there something I am doing wrong or there is any other way to format numbers that I should use ?

Comment: You format works for me just fine when I try to format `1000`, i.e. I get `1,000`.  Can you please show me the code where you are using `df`?

Comment: @azurefrog I think IndexOutofBound means that he wants `1000` to be formatted as `1000`, not `1,000`.

Comment: Ah, reading comprehension issue then. :/

Comment: @azurefrog No, it's the fault of the question: "1000 does not get converted to 1,000". I'm starting to think that when he tries to format `1000`, he gets `1000`, but wants `1,000`, which would mean that he's doing something else wrong.

Comment: The decimal format works as expected there is some other part of code that I am using that messes up the formatting. Thank you every one for helping out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
```

The `DecimalFormat` is locale specific and can interpret format symbols differently depending on the system locale.